# Model theory of many-sorted first-order logic

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

I know that, traditionally, model theory studies single-sorted structures. But, has anyone developed a model theory for many-sorted structures? For example, in the theory of vector spaces, we have two sorts $K$ and $V$, where $K$ is a field and $V$ is the vector space itself, and we also have a scalar multiple function $f : K \times V \rightarrow V$. The function $f$ is a mixed-sorted operation. Also, in plane geometry, there is a sort for points and a sort for lines, and we have a binary operation that takes two distinct points and gives the unique line connecting them. Has anyone, in some book or paper, defined this notion rigorously and developed theory based on it?

Comment: Yes. Searching for the term "many-sorted logic" will call up many hits. For example, Manzano's book *Extensions of first-order logic*. I'm not sure what you're looking for that you're not finding; can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, there are some decent notes by Alex Kruckman where the whole theory of first-order logic and models is developed using many-sorted logic. Most of the main properties of one-sorted logic, like completeness, compactness, Lowenheim-Skolem, etc. generalise perfectly well. https://akruckman.faculty.wesleyan.edu/files/2019/07/Lecture-Notes.pdf

Comment: Just to make it clear, the ideas worked out in the notes Mark links to are not at all original to me. At the research level, model theorists use multi-sorted first-order logic all the time. Unfortunately, there are no textbooks on the subject that introduce the multi-sorted context from the very start. Instead, when a textbook needs multiple sorts for the first time (usually when introducing Shelah's $M^{\mathrm{eq}}$ construction), we get a statement like "all of the previous results go through essentially without change in the multi-sorted setting". (This is true, of course.)

Comment: The single-sorted setting is certainly easier to grasp when you meet model theory for the first time, so I understand the pedagogical reason for starting with just one sort. But I wrote these notes to fill the gap in the introductory literature and demonstrate that there are really no difficult issues at all with developing the basics of model theory in the multi-sorted setting (*and* allowing empty structures and empty sorts).